# C++: Custom return value for different types of template function (method)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Motivation - in abstract mathematics we can generalise 3-dimensional cross product to n dimensions, assuming that for two vectors `v,w` of dimension `n`, their cross product will have dimension `n(n-1)/2`. Skipping the ideas of differential forms, I would like to converse this idea into the language of templates in C++ library. I had this idea:

```
auto Cross(const Vec<dim, float_t> &rhs) {
    if (dim == 0)return;
    if (dim == 1)return (float_t)0;
    if (dim == 2)return Values[0] * rhs.Values[1] - Values[1] * rhs.Values[0];
    if (dim == 3)return Vec<dim, float_t>(
        Values[1] * rhs.Values[2] - Values[2] * rhs.Values[1], 
        Values[2] * rhs.Values[0] - Values[0] * rhs.Values[2], 
        Values[0] * rhs.Values[1] - Values[1] * rhs.Values[0]);

    //...
}
```

but sadly, `auto` specifier doesn't allow for different return types. I could of course mess with preprocessor, but I believe that there is more clever way to do it, something like:

```
Vec<dim*(dim-1)/2,float_t> Cross(const Vec<dim,float_t> &rhs);
```

(with `void` as a special case for zero-dimensional point and just `float_t` for one-dimensional point). How to solve this in a smart way?

Comment: Write overloaded/specialization functions that take either a `const Vec<0, float_t> &` parameter, or a `const Vec<1, float_t> &` parameter, etc... Each overloaded/specialized function will have an appropriate return type for it.

Comment: In C++17 you'll be able to do this with `if constexpr`, but until that's available you'll have to use specializations like in @alfC's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implent this is by means of specializations. Without specialization it would be very hard to implement a truly generic template algorithm, (which I would be interested to see).

If you use specializations you can't use `auto` for the most part, the return types will have to be explicit. This should do what you want:

```
#include<cassert>
#include<array>

using std::array;

template<std::size_t Dim>
array<double, Dim*(Dim-1)/2> 
Cross(array<double, Dim> const&, array<double, Dim> const&);

template<> array<double, 0> Cross(
    array<double, 1> const&, array<double, 1> const& v2
){return {};}

template<> array<double, 1> Cross(
    array<double, 2> const& v1, array<double, 2> const& v2
){return {{v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0]}};}

template<> array<double, 3> Cross(
    array<double, 3> const& v1, array<double, 3> const& v2
){
    return {{
        v1[1] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[1], 
        v1[2] * v2[0] - v1[0] * v2[2], 
        v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0]
    }};
}

int main(){
    array<double, 1> v1{{1.}};
    array<double, 2> v2{{1.,2.}};
    array<double, 3> v3{{1.,2., 3.}};

    assert(( Cross(v1, v1) == array<double, 0>{} ));
    assert(( Cross(v2, v2)[0] == 0. ));
    assert(( Cross(v3, v3)[0] == 0. ));
}
```

Now at this point, if you know you are going to work with (total) specializations (like the above), there is little difference between this and separate overloads of `Cross` (except enforcing a certain return type defined in 6th line of code.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could do this:

```
template <std::size_t dim>
auto cross(const Vec<dim, float_t>& rhs)
{
    /*logic goes here, also you can generalize*/    
}
```

This will create new function for each `dim` (implicitly). Also, try to do it at compile time rather than runtime by using specializations.

Comment: Yeah, i read somewhere example code with if's, author claimed that this would be solved on compiling time. I still don't know if that's true, but it gave me this idea here. Thanks for help!